# How come using @username doesn't always work?

Tags: support

When I add a comment and try to use @username sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Is there anything in http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/843/how-do-references-work that gives an explanation?

Comment: `any commenter who wrote a comment for the same question` then how come I cant @Patrick Kenny after he commented [over here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192103/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-on-registration-to-a-specific-node) ?

Comment: The question was asked by him, so he will be notified of any comments left under his question. The same applies for the users who write an answer, for comments left under their answers. That is under _Are there users that are automatically notified of a comment?_